# How can I know if the $http response is brought from cache - Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, caching

is there any indication from `$http` if the response brought from the cache?
For example lets say I have made this two calls:

```
$http.get({url, cache: true).then(function(response, ..., moreData) { alert(moreData.fromCache) }) //alerts false 

$http.get({url, cache: true).then(function(response, ..., moreData) { alert(moreData.fromCache) }) //alerts true
```

as you can see the first call is really executing an ajax call so it is not from cache, the second one brings the data from cache so it alerting true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that information is exposed - the documentation mentions that even if the resource is cached, the request (using the cache) will still be asynchronous, so it'll look like any other request. The only thing I can think of is rolling your own cache and using that to know when a successful lookup has occurred. From the documentation:

> You can change the default cache to a new object (built with
>   $cacheFactory) by updating the $http.defaults.cache property. All
>   requests who set their cache property to true will now use this cache
>   object.

Comment: I hope there is still that there is some indication if the data is from cache or not. If there is no such indication I think it would be a very nice feature

Answer (score 1):

You can see if the call was cached through the Chrome developer tools by watching the Network tab. It will tell you if it was cached or if it was called.

Comment: I need it to be programmatically

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to determine if something is cached with request and response handlers with a caveat.  This `ONLY` handles the case where the first request completed `BEFORE` the second one was made.  If you make 2 `requests` before the first one gets back, which the angular cache will handle like a charm and only make 1 service call, both will appear as not cached, which is technically true since they were both waiting on the first request to be cached, but may not be what you wanted.

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function() {
    return {
        'request': function requestInterceptor(config) {
            if (config.cache) {
                //Determine if a custom cache object is being used
                var cache = angular.isObject(config.cache) ? config.cache : $http.defaults.cache;
                config.wasCached = cache.get(config.url) ? true : false;
            }

            return config;
        },

        'response': function(response) {
            if (response && response.config && response.config.wasCached) {
                console.log('Was Cached!')
            } 
            return response;
        }
    };
});
```